# Use actuator security together with spring resource server

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot-actuator, spring-resource-server

I am trying to use OAuth 2.0 to secure my API's endpoints together with the default actuator security. I can get either of them to work independently but not together

For OAuth, I have the following FilterChain

```
    public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                        sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        return http.build();
    }
```

My spring security configuration looks likes this

```
  security:
    user.name: admin
    user.password: somepassword
    oauth2:
      resource-server:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: {MY ISSUER URI}
```

I also have `management.security.enabled=true`

I would expect that the actuator endpoints use basic authentication asking for username and password and all other endpoints should use OAuth.

I have also tried adding a second FilterChain with different order for actuator, but that also doesn't work

```
 @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 1)
    public SecurityFilterChain actuatorFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/**")).authenticated()
                ).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

Is there a standard way to implement this usecase?